# Encoding apostrophe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, encoding

i am building up a string on the server that is getting put into a javascript variable on the client.

what is the best of encoding this to avoid any issues

right now on the server i am doing something like this:

```
 html = html.Replace("'", "&#39;");
```

but i assume there is a more elegant fool proof way of doing stuff like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're really better off using the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en) to do this. They provide a JavaScriptEncode method that does what you want:

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode("My 'Quotes' and ""more"".", False)
```

Comment: Don't forget to unescape it on the front-end if you want to use it for an alert box for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
html = html.Replace("'", "%27");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in which context you're using this string, but `\'` might be what you're looking for. The backslash is an escape character and allows you to use [certain characters](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/tucows/html/programmer/jstut/jsTabChars.html) that can't otherwise be present in a string literal. This is what the output JavaScript should look like:

```
alert('It\'s amazing');
```

Of course, you could use `alert("It's amazing");` in this particular case.

Anyway, if you're building JavaScript code:

```
html = html.Replace("'", "\\'");
```

On the other hand, there are other characters besides apostrophes that need some processing. Using the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en) would get all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the AntiXSS library was not able to accomplish what I was looking for, which was to encode server side and decode in javascript.

Instead I used Microsoft.JScript.dll which allows you to:

```
GlobalObject.escape(string);
```

and on the client side in javascript:

```
unescape(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The characters that you need to escape in a string value are the backslash and the character used as string delimiter.

If apostrophes (') are used as string delimiter:

```
html = html.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'");
```

If quotation marks (") are used as string delimiter:

```
html = html.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

If you don't know which delimiter is used, or if it may change in the future, you can just escape both:

```
html = html.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("'", @"\'").Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```